# How to modify .xlsx containing pictures with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, image, openpyxl, xlsx

I need to modify existing .xlsx file which contains graphs in form of pictures from other program. When I try to modify it with openpyxl I lose all pictures which were previously in file. Even with a simple modification like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
wb2.create_sheet('sid1')
wb2.save('template.xlsx')
```

Is there a way to modify (add new sheets containing new data) without losing pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) documentation on **Read an existing workbook** there is a warning mentioned that the images/charts can't be read by `openpyxl`

[image]